# Restart Go's net/http server on file-change like Django

Tags: go, httpserver, martini

I'm trying out Martini, which adds some nice functionality upon Go's basic `net/http` package.

I was wondering tho. How can I, like Django does too, let the server restart itself on source-file changes? I know how to monitor a file, but I'm not sure how to retrigger the Server within the same process.

I'm guessing to trigger `http.ListenAndServe` again, but I have a feeling it doesn't go well with instance already running.

Do I need to spawn a subprocess/daemon to get this working?

Comment: Are you talking source file (compiled) changes or resources?  For the former you'll need an external process to watch your source since a recompile is needed. For the latter, Martini seems to serve the latest, at least in development mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe you need [gin](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) ?

Made by the creator of Martini.

Comment: Wonderfully simple. Thank you :)

Comment: Gin starts the server in one port, but I'm using the mux router. What is conflicting ports.

Comment: Gin is not maintained anymore, as you can read in various issues on Github, like here: https://github.com/codegangsta/gin/issues/90 "This project is abandoned."

Comment: Gin is by no means abandoned and its development is ongoing. The have regularly commits

Answer (score 14):

You may give it a try

[Fresh](https://github.com/pilu/fresh) is a command line tool that builds and (re)starts your web application everytime you save a Go or template file.

Comment: By far the most user-friendly package I've tried to date.  Great recommendation!

Comment: This will make go development fun!

Comment: Fresh is now unmaintained

Answer (score 12):

You'll need to use an external tool that can watch a directory/files and run a command. I'd recommend [reflex](https://github.com/cespare/reflex) which is written in Go itself:

(modifying the example in the README):

```
# Rerun make whenever a .go file changes
reflex -r '\.go$' ./mymartiniapp
```